# Round Half Down in VB.Net

Tags: .net, vb.net

Can anyone give me some help on how to round half down in Visual Basic? 
I need `0.555` to be converted to `0.55` and NOT `0.56.`

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

It's not entirely clear what you're trying to achieve but for the example you've given you could:

- Multiply by 100 giving 55.5
- Use [Math.Floor](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.math.floor.aspx) giving 55.0
- Then divide back by 100 to give the answer 0.55

However, this approach will always round down.

If you want to specify how to handle the midpoint value 0.005 and always round this down you'll have to try something else. Have a look at [Math.Round](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f5898377.aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=vb#code-snippet-1) and in particular the [MidpointRounding mode](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.midpointrounding.aspx). Using 'ToEven' you could conceivably multiply by 100 split the number into fractional and integer parts, round the fractional part using 'ToEven' then add it back to the integer value and finally divide again.

Make sure you think about how you need both positive and negative values to behave.

Answer (score 1):

This should do it:

```
Dim res = Math.Truncate(0.555 * 100) / 100
```

Answer (score 0):

you can try math.floor, this will round down http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k7ycc7xh.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Just to be insane (probably requires some testing around edge cases):

Also, probably isn't good to check for "."

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.numberformatinfo.numberdecimalseparator.aspx

```
  public double FunkyRound( double test, int places )
  {
     string valueString = test.ToString();
     // if the string has a decimal and ends with 5, just remove the last 5 and return
     if ( valueString.EndsWith( "5" ) && valueString.Contains(".") )
     {
        valueString = valueString.Substring( 0, valueString.Length - 1 ); // trim the last "5"
        return double.Parse( valueString );
     }
     else
     {
        // just do regular rounding
        return Math.Round( test, places );
     }
  }
```